# Por que no cambia el valor la variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Tengo el siguiente código donde inicializo tres variables `g_turno`,`g_sucursal`,`g_fecha` con un valor cualquiera.

Estas variables deben de cambiar su valor respectivamente cuando las señales siguientes se activen:

```
self.turno_1.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.turno_online(self.turno_1.currentText()))
self.sucursal.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.sucursal_online(self.sucursal.currentText()))
self.fecha.dateChanged.connect(self.cambio_fecha)
```

Posteriormente cuando la señal `self.turno_1.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.turno_online(self.turno_1.currentText()))`

se activa ejecuta la siguiente acción:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def turno_online(self,str):
    g_turno = str
    if str == 'Mañana':
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        editar(self.tabla_1,g_sucursal,g_fecha,g_turno)
    else:
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        editar(self.tabla_2,g_sucursal,g_fecha,g_turno)
```

cuando ejecuto la funcion de editar le mando como argumentos el valor de las variables anteriormente definidas, sin embargo el problema esta en que las variables conservan el mismo valor.

Este es el codigo completo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from Acces import *
import time
from editar_campos import editar


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("new_exe.ui",self)

        global g_turno 
        g_turno =  'Matutino'
        global g_sucursal
        g_sucursal =  'Exe 1'
        global g_fecha
        g_fecha = str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

        self.fecha.dateChanged.connect(self.cambio_fecha)
        self.turno_1.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.turno_online(self.turno_1.currentText()))
        self.sucursal.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.sucursal_online(self.sucursal.currentText()))



    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QDate)
    def cambio_fecha(self,fecha):
        g_fecha = fecha.toPyDate()
        print(g_fecha)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def turno_online(self,str):
        g_turno = str
        if str == 'Mañana':
            self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
            editar(self.tabla_1,g_sucursal,g_fecha,g_turno)
        else:
            self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
            editar(self.tabla_2,g_sucursal,g_fecha,g_turno)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def sucursal_online(self,str):
        g_sucursal = str




app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: podrias mostrar que hace la función `editar(...)`, ademas evita usar variables globales, es una mala práctica su abuso, y pienso que estas abusando.

Comment: @eyllanesc, la función solo imprime el contenido de las variables q recibe como argumentos.

Comment: Que recomendarias en vez de variables globales

Comment: atributos de la clase, por ejemplo `self.g_sucursal`

Comment: Tú dices: *sin embargo el problema esta en que las variables conservan el mismo valor.* ¿Qué variables conservan su valor? ¿que es tabla_1, tabla_2?

Comment: ¿Qué es `turno_1` y `sucursal`? ¿son QComboboxs?

Comment: Las bariables q defini como globales no cambian su valor , turno1 y sucursal son qcombobox las tablas son qtablewidget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No uses variables globales si no es necesario, y en tu caso no lo son, pero ademas de ello no lo sabes utilizar, cuando quieres editar una variable global debes señalar que lo es, por ejemplo en el método `cambio_fecha()` tú deseas asignar un nuevo valor a `g_fecha`, entonces debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QDate)
def cambio_fecha(self,fecha):
    global g_fecha # <--- señalando que modifique la variable global
    g_fecha = fecha.toPyDate()
    print(g_fecha)
```

Pero como señalo no es la mejor opción, ahorita mismo te esta traendo problemas, e imagina cuantos problemas te traera en un futuro. Y lo peor es que los principiantes piensan que es algo mágico y abusan de ellos.

La mejor opción es usar atributos de la clase ya que su ambito es de la clase y podrás acceder a ello fácilmente.

Por otro lado si puedes evitar lambda, evitalos. En tu caso pienso que `turno_1` y `sucursal` tienen la señal `currentTextChanged`, asi que usalo directamente.

Por último no uses str como parámetro de una funcion, `str` es una función y los estas solapando, en el caso del decorado `pyqtSlot()` su uso es correcto ya que ese decorador requiere como dato el tipo de dato que recibira el slot.

Como señalas que la funcion `editar()` solo imprime lo he cambiado por un `print()`

```
class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("new_exe.ui",self)

        self.g_turno =  'Matutino'
        self.g_sucursal =  'Exe 1'
        self.g_fecha = str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

        self.fecha.dateChanged.connect(self.cambio_fecha)
        self.turno_1.currentTextChanged.connect(self.turno_online)
        self.sucursal.currentTextChanged.connect(self.sucursal_online)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QDate)
    def cambio_fecha(self,fecha):
        self.g_fecha = fecha.toPyDate()
        print(self.g_fecha)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def turno_online(self, turno):
        self.g_turno = turno
        if turno == 'Mañana':
            self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
            print(self.tabla_1, self.g_sucursal, self.g_fecha, self.g_turno)
        else:
            self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
            print(self.tabla_2, self.g_sucursal, self.g_fecha, self.g_turno)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def sucursal_online(self, sucursal):
        self.g_sucursal = sucursal
```